# Can I use a regex to enter an if statement in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

What's going on is I'm parsing an /etc/passwd file to pull out the usernames and first/last name of each person in the file. Can I use a regex to get in to my if statement? Here's an example of a line I'm trying to match:

```
$parameter = cvwalters:*:14608:140608:Chris V. Walters,N/A,N/A,N/A:/home/cvwalters:/bin/bash

if ($parameter =~ /(.+):(.+):(.+):(.+):(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+):(.+):(.+)/){
    my $uid =$1;
    my $fname = $5 =~ /^\W+/;
    my $lname = $5 =~ /\W+$/;
    push (@results, $uid, $fname, $lname);
}
```

Does perl return a true boolean there to the if statement and allow the rest to execute? If not, how can I make that happen?

Comment: You will be much happier if you just split on the colon.

Comment: So the question is if the `m//` operator returns Boolean true/false in Boolean context?  This is covered in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators (or on any system that has Perl installed, `perldoc perlop`)

Comment: `split /[,:]/, $parameter`, or `$parameter =~ /([^:,]+)/g` would work in addition to just splitting on the colon like squiguy suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in boolean context, the match operator is a boolean operator.

But please take the advice of @squiguy, use split.

There is even a passwd module on CPAN.

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Unix-ConfigFile/PasswdFile.pm

Comment: Can't use modules, it's for an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

So this would be the better option then I take it....

```
$parameter = cvwalters:*:14608:140608:Chris V. Walters,N/A,N/A,N/A:/home/cvwalters:/bin/bash

my ($uid, $junk, $junk2, $junk3, $name, $junk4, $junk5) = split /:/, $parameter;

my $fname = $name =~ /^\w+/;
my $lname = $name =~ /\w+$/;

push (@results, $uid, $fname, $lname);
```

Comment: `my ($uid, undef, undef, undef, $name) = split /:/, $parameter;` - no need for those `$junk` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
my $var = "cvwalters:*:14608:140608:Chris V. Walters,N/A,N/A,N/A:/home/cvwalters:/bin/bash";
my @arr = split /[:,]/, $var;
my $uid = $arr[0];
my ($fname) = $arr[4] =~ /^(\w+)/;
my ($lname) = $arr[4] =~ /(\w+)$/;
push(@results,$uid,$fname,$lname);
```